# What does it mean when a variable returns "Stale == TRUE"

Tags: pyomo

I am working on a very large scheduling problem. My strategy is to limit the number of jobs to schedule to make a selection out of the whole pool of jobs in the first round, then schedule the selected jobs, and return to the first step. 
I realized that if I do not select more than 30-40 jobs, the optimization runs smoothly. However as I increase the number of selected jobs the optimization runs though, but several variables return the value "None".
As I see their flag "Stale" is turned to TRUE.

I am quite clueless here, but first of all I would like to understand what this flag "Stale" exactly means. I hope if someone would clarify the meaning of it, it would be easier for me to hunt down my bug.

I use the "CBC" solver. I did try with other, but even with smaller sized problems they did not return an acceptable solution.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stale` flag indicates whether or not a variable's value was updated with the most recent call to a solver. If a variable's `stale` flag is True it usually means that the variable did not appear in any of the active model constraints that were sent to the solver.

Comment: Many thanks, and sorry for the late reply, I managed to find a get around solution

Comment: How to check if a variable is Stale or not? How to count them ? 
for example let's have a. variable like instance.x[i] 
Let's assume some of these x[i] are Stale , how to count them ?

Comment: printing: instance.x.pprint() gives you the boolean column "Stale" number 2 from the right:)